# Javascript on change not working on [object html select element]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is what i have tried so far:

```js
var getJqInputs = function(html) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = html;
  return el.childNodes[0];
}
alert(getJqInputs(document.getElementById("select").outerHTML));
/*getJqInputs(document.getElementById("select").outerHTML).addEventListener("change", function(){
    alert("sd");   
});*/
getJqInputs(document.getElementById("select").outerHTML).onchange = function() {
  alert("dhhj");
};
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option id="someid" name="1" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="2" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="3" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="4" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="5" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="6" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="7" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="8" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="9" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="20" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="23" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
</select>
```

I only have text in my actual scenario, i'm getting a dom object out of it and then trying to add change event on it. My purpose is to get name attribute for each option selected, but no luck

Although JQuery is more easy but, I can only use Javascript.

I've got the idea to convert html string to DOM from [here](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Revealing-the-magic-how-to-properly-convert-HTML-string-to-a-DOM-element)

My question is how to add change event when you have an object  of HTMLSelectElement ? (not to get from id or class)

Comment: You are right about jQuery being [easier](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/a5cgfd0t/)

Also, make sure that you are not using duplicate ID in the options of the select.

Answer (score 1):

You've got quite a bit of extra, unneeded code here. You simply need to find the selected option when the list changes, and pull its attribute value by name:

```js
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener('change', function() {
    alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name'));
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option id="someid" name="1" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="2" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="3" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="4" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="5" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="6" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="7" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="8" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="9" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="20" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
  <option id="someid" name="23" class="someclass">Subhan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yea thats right, but i need to do it that way, because in my scenario all i get is a select but in the form of text. I'm manually making it an object

Comment: that method i've got from here http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Revealing-the-magic-how-to-properly-convert-HTML-string-to-a-DOM-element

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare a JSON object in a very simple syntax as shown in the code.
2. Then simply call the `Build()`-function, and pass in the object constructor (Select) and the JSON object (dropdown).

## Syntax ----- Build(Select, dropdown)

//CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    //ON VALUE CHANGE       
    var valChange = function(ele) { 
        console.log(ele.value);
    };    
    //SIMPLE JSON SYNTAX
    var dropdown = [
        {"select":{"element": "select", "attributes": {"id":"select","onchange":"valChange(this)"}}},
        {"opt1":{"element": "option", "attributes": {"id":"opt1","class":"someclass"}}},
        {"opt2":{"element": "option", "attributes": {"id":"opt2","class":"someclass"}}},
        {"opt3":{"element": "option", "attributes": {"id":"opt3","class":"someclass"}}}
    ];
    //BUILD FUNCTION TAKES TO PARAMETERS OBJECT (CONSTRUCTOR,JSON-OBJECT)
    function Build(obj,json){
        var select = new Construct(obj,json);
        Assemble(select);
        Create(select);
    }
    //OBJECT CONSTRUCTOR (SELECT) 
    //THE PROPERTIES OF THE OBJECT ARE DECLARED DYNAMICALLY
    function Select(){
        for(var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++){
            var key = Object.keys(arguments[i]);
            this[key] = arguments[i][key];
        }   
    }
    //CREATES A NEW OBJECT AND APPLYS PROPERTIES
    //CALLED FROM THE BUILD FUNCTION
    //TAKES TO ARGUEMENTS - OBJ(CONSTRUCTOR), ARGS(JSON-OBJECT) 
    function Construct(obj,args){
        var Fake = new obj;
        obj.apply(Fake, args);
        return Fake;
    }
    //ASSEMBLES THE HTML ELEMENTS FROM THE OBJECT PROPERTIES AND APPLIES THE ATTRIBUTES & VALUES
    function Assemble(obj){
        for(key in obj){
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                var element = document.createElement(obj[key].element);
                var attributes = obj[key].attributes;
                for(prop in attributes){
                    if(attributes.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                        element.setAttribute(prop, attributes[prop]);
                        obj[key] = element;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }       
    }
    //APPENDS THE OBJECT TO THE ACTUAL DOCUMENT
    function Create(obj){
        var opts = Object.keys(obj).splice(1);
        var select = document.body.appendChild(obj.select);
        for(i=0; i < opts.length; i++){
            select.appendChild(obj[opts[i]]).innerHTML = "Subhan" + i;
        }           
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: i only have a fixed html string how can i add inline to that?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed add the onchange attribute on the select element, as shown in the code above. When the value changes of the select element... example when someone selects something... then the event will trigger.

Comment: dear i have a string with some text, i'm converting it into object, how to add inline to a string? dynamically

Comment: @SubhanAhmed post the string so I can see it.

Comment: i have posted it. thats in the form of a string actually, my method getjqinputs is converting it into a dom object.

Comment: @SubhanAhmed Okay I see what your doing... yea if you add the element via the innerHTML method it doesn't declared to the DOM, I wrote  a OOP framework which will handle object creation, I'll update the code and show you want I mean.

Comment: @SubhanAhmed sorry had to do something real fast just got back, will post shortly

Comment: @SubhanAhmed code is updated let me know if you have any questions... we can move the convo to chat to if you would like.

Comment: I don't have to use prototype or jquery. simple javascript is the only thing i need.

Comment: Is there any way for it is plain js?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed this is plain javascript, the prototype method is just declaring a constructor method of an object, in this case the Select() function. If you don't wish to use it you could just replace the Select.prototype.create() with Create() or any other naming convention and it will would work fine. The code is way cleaner however the way I have it where your declaring a method (sub-function) of an object in this case the Select() function where only objects created from the Select() function (constructor) inherit the create() method.

Comment: @SubhanAhmed if this still confuses you I can update the code removing the prototypes very simply, however I'd advise you learn how to use them in the future. Here is a good reference if you do want to learn http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/

Comment: Thanks a'lot for you time Jordan. I'd be happy if you make it more readable. You can also JQuery instead of prototype. (i'll manage that).

Comment: @SubhanAhmed okay just updated the code. let me know if you need help understanding it.

Comment: Some documentation please

Comment: @SubhanAhmed okay just updated the code with comments, it should be pretty straight forward at this point, if it's not then let me know and I'll explain in chat.